# Radius of Convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{z^{3^n}-z^{2\cdot 3^n}}n$

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis, power-series

Consider the power series
$$g(z)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{z^{3^n}-z^{2 \cdot 3^n}}{n}.$$
We can see that $\limsup_{n \to \infty} |a_n|^{1/n}=0$ so by Cauchy-Hadamard we know that the radius of convergence is $\infty$ and the series consequently converges everywhere. But, when we let $z=e^{i \pi/3}$ the series diverges. What is going wrong here?

Comment: $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sup |a_n|^{1/n}$ is NOT $0$. By definition, we have $a_{3^n}=\frac1n$ and then $|a_{3^n}|^{3^{-n}}=n^{-3^{-n}}\to1$ as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: @jjagmath  I cannot see why $a_{3^n}\neq \frac1n$. Maybe I'm missing something. Can you elaborate more?

Comment: @Feng Thanks, that clears it up. $e^{i\pi/3}$ is on the boundary now so $g$ does not necessarily need to converge there.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez  Why not? It can be seen as $\sum a_k z^k$ with  $a_{3^n}=\frac1n$ and $a_{2\cdot 3^n}=-\frac1n$.

Comment: This is NOT a power series.

Comment: It is a rearrangement of a power series, so asking about the radius of convergence makes sense: strictly inside that radius it converges absolutely, so the rearrangement also converges.  But (conceivably) the OP series could converge conditionally somewhere on the boundary of convergence even if the corresponding power series does not; or vice versa.

Comment: @GérardLetac why is this not a power series?

Comment: This is a  series of polynomials, not monomials...